# Cannot read property 'fileSize' of undefined (req.file) (multer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

**CODE:**

```
var upload = multer({dest:"./uploads"});

app.post("/", upload.single("file"), function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.file.fileSize+"bytes");                     
});
```

EJS FILE:

```
    <h1>Get the File Size of your Upload !</h1>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/" name="file">
    <input type="file" class="form-control">
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

**QUESTION:**

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: Are you getting the file in `req.file`?

Comment: @Pete It's `undefined` if I log it to the console. So no.

Comment: You haven't specified the field name as a parameter to `.single`

Comment: Can you try with `path` `var upload = multer({
  dest: path.join(__dirname, './uploads')
});`

Comment: @Pete Did not change anything

Comment: @jcaron I can put any string there, right ? (did not change anything)

Comment: You need to give a `name` to your input, and use the same name as parameter to `.single`

Comment: @jcaron did not work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add name = 'file' to input

```
<h1>Get the File Size of your Upload !</h1>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file">
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```